# For what $z$ does the sequence $z_n=nz^n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For what $z$ does the sequence $z_n=nz^n$ converge?

*Attempt*

Consider $\sum_{n\geq 1}nz^n $ and notice
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{z_{n+1}}{z_n}=(1+\frac{1}{n})z=z$$

but the serie converges iff $|z|<1$ therefore

$z_n$ converges iff $|z|<1$ and in fact $z_n \to 0$

Is my answer right?  or I should consider

$z^n=\cos n \theta+ i \sin n \theta$ and consider the limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left( \cos n \theta+i \sin n \theta \right)$$ and
compare
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n \left( \cos n \theta \right)\wedge \lim_{n \to \infty} n \left( i\sin n \theta \right)$$

There exists a general form of attack this kind of problem, when they request see for what values of $z$ a given sequence converges?

Comment: You’ve asked two different questions:  do you want the sequence or the series to converge?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Use $a_n = nz^n$. To prove $a_n \to 0$, you can prove: $|a_n| \to 0$. Thus $|a_n| = n|z|^n, |z| < 1$ as indicated in your post. You have: $|a_n| = \dfrac{n}{b^n}$, $b = \dfrac{1}{|z|} > 1$. Thus put $b = x+1, x > 0\implies |a_n| = \dfrac{n}{(1+x)^n} < \dfrac{n}{1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2}} < \dfrac{2}{(n-1)x^2}\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ while $x$ is fixed, proving the assertion !

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, now, There exists a general way to solve this kind of problems?, and the $x$ exists by axiom of choice?

Comment: @JuanT: No, $x = b - 1$. You need not use the powerful AC as the knowledge of set theory about the existence of certain element or number is not required for this question.

Comment: Right, thanks for the explanation